# Evaluate the sum $1+2+3+...+n$

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

How do we evaluate the sum:

\begin{equation*}
1+2+...+n
\end{equation*}

I don't need the proof with the mathematical induction, but the technique to evaluate this series.

Comment: $$1+2+3+ \ldots + (n-1) +n = n+1 + (n-1)+2 + (n-2) +3+\ldots = n+1+n+1+n+1+ \ldots$$

Answer (score 5):

Turn it backwards and sum those two together. Notice something?

Comment: I cannot understand your answer. Is there another way to evaluate it?

Comment: @george Write the sequence and it's inverse below one another. Then add.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}2\cdot (1 + 2 + \cdots + n) &= 1 + 2 + \cdots + (n - 1) + n + 
\\& + n + (n-1) + \cdots + 2 + 1 \end{align}$$

Now, add the numbers in the same column together.

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that if you add the first term with the last the sum of these two is $n+1$. Now add the second term with the prelast then you get that the sum of these two is again $n+1$. Continue with the same way.

Only one term will remain unattached. Can you extract the result that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

*This is what Gauss did when he evaluated for the first time this sum at school!!*

Comment: Elementary school as far as i remember! :) But not sure.

Comment: Yes. It is elementary school. It is the first sum students learn in elementary school. :)

Answer (score 0):

The average term is $\frac {n+1}2$ and there are $n$ of them. To see this, take the average of $n$ and $1$, of $n-1$ and $2$ etc - at each stage the average of the pair is $\frac {n+1}2$ and if you have a single number left at the end, it will be the central one i.e. $\frac {n+1}2$.

This is not so slick as the reverse and add method, and is wholly equivalent to it. So this answer is just in case it helps you to understand. I have found the concept of average term $\times$ number of terms useful as a shorthand for arithmetic progressions in general, rather than remembering a formula.